# Compare values ​from two arrays and generate a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two arrays that may or may not have similar values

```
const arrayOne = [orange, red, black, blue, yellow]
const arrayTwo = [blue, purple, white, red]
```

I'm using react and in `useEffect` I want that when making a certain change through `onClick` it returns the values ​​that are not the same

example:-

```
const = [orange, purple, black, white, yellow]
```

I have tried the following ...

```
const [newArray, setNewArray] = useState([])
const [reload, setReload] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const results = arrayOne.filter((i) => {
      return (
        i.id != arrayTwo.id
      )
      setNewArray(results)
    })
  }, [reload])

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setReload(!reload) }>
      Trigger useEffect
    </button>
  )
```

Comment: How `useEffect` related to `onClick` event?

Comment: @DennisVash I didn't pass the dependency array that makes useEffect load

Comment: You asking to return values that are not the same but in your example you return the same items `[blue,red]`, what is the logic behind this?

Comment: @DennisVash I made the adjustments

Comment: You can use lodash's `xor` like `_.xor(arrayOne, arrayTwo)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the similar items, and then filter accordingly:

```js
const arrayOne = ['orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow']
const arrayTwo = ['blue', 'purple', 'white', 'red']

// [red,blue]
const dupItems = arrayOne.filter(item => arrayTwo.includes(item));

const output = [...arrayOne.filter(item => !dupItems.includes(item)), ...arrayTwo.filter(item => !dupItems.includes(item))];
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function diff (a1, a2) {

    var a = [], diff = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i]]) {
            delete a[a2[i]];
        } else {
            a[a2[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    for (var k in a) {
        diff.push(k);
    }

    return diff;
}

// call here 
diff( ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to do it this way:

```js
let arrayOne=['orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'yellow'];

let arrayTwo=['blue', 'purple', 'white', 'red'];

let common=arrayOne.filter(value => arrayTwo.includes(value))

let result=[...new Set([...arrayOne,...arrayTwo])].filter(value=>common.indexOf(value)==-1)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work

```
const diffArray = arrayOne.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if ((arrayTwo.inclues(value) { return acc; }
  return acc.concat([value]);
}, []);
```

Note: please check for typos on my code I'm answering from my phone